# How to parameterize an rmarkdown in blogdown?

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

Thanks to [parameterized reports](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) support by `Rmarkdown`, it is easy to make an `.Rmd` file rendered with parameters as follows (this example is from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-quick-tip-parameter-re-use-within-rmarkdown-yaml/)):

```
---
title: "`r params$dynamictitle`"
params:
  dynamictitle: My report
  reportdate: !r Sys.Date()
date: "`r params$reportdate`"
---
```

This would be fine to knit to a `.html` file, but cannot be rendered in `blogdown`, with the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 2-5 () 
<simpleError in eval(parse_only(code), envir = envir): object 'params' not found>
```

I want to know whether there is a workaround way to make an `.Rmd` file parameterized?

Comment: Try putting `params` before the title in the YAML like it is in the example.

Comment: @RyanMorton It is of no use, because they are the same. What's more, the lines I put here work well when rendering with normal `rmarkdown`.

Comment: You may have good reason to want to use parameterized Rmd. Usually it is because you want to use the same Rmd multiple times with different parameters. But in the case of a blogdown, the Rmd file will only be knit once. This means that you can only use it once with a unique set of parameters. Why don't you put these parameters in the first chunk of your Rmd file, like usual R code ?

Comment: @SébastienRochette Thank you for your comment. But I would like to set several parameters used to generate field values of the front matter for the `.Rmd`. If these parameters are set in the first chunk, I cannot access those values in the front matter part.

Comment: Well, you can directly put it in the final place. Like in 'title' or 'date' as in your example. This allows for R code. Do you need to use the same parameter in many places ? BTW, you should fix the date for your article because each time you compile again your blogdown, the date will change.

Comment: The point here is that there are several values being used several times both in the front matter and the main body parts. So if the `params` is supported, I could set these values in `params`, and then use it anywhere in the document.